# jquery: Creating a responsive datagrid

Tags: jquery, html, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a responsive datagrid in wich I can edit and add rows. The rows come from a database, and upon edit or creation of a new row it should be updated/inserted in the database.
In the old days I would just have used a plain form and a submit to handle the data in PHP, now I'm trying to learn the same stuff in a more modern way.

I've come a long way already, I can update a row and a can insert a new one, returning the id and using it in the table. What however doesn't work is updatein a row that was just inserted. When I click the edit icon for such a row, it does seem to go to edit mode, but instead it is inserting a new row in the background. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

I'm also wondering if there is a less complicated way to do this, it seems I have to write a load of code for a table with just 3 fields, any advice?

The HTML part looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="schedules">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Time from</th>
                    <th>Time to</th>
                    <th>Enabled</th>
                                        <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                                <tr id="1">
                    <td id="time_from">16:01</td>
                    <td id="time_to">23:01</td>
                    <td id="enabled">true</td>
                    <td id="edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-fw" id="editicon"></i></td>
                </tr>
                                <tr id="2">
                    <td id="time_from">10:00</td>
                    <td id="time_to">11:00</td>
                    <td id="enabled">false</td>
                    <td id="edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-fw" id="editicon"></i></td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>

            <i class="fa fa-plus" id="addRow"></i>
```

The javascrip/jquery part looks like this:

```
<script>
                //function for when the addrow action is used
                $('#addRow').on('click',function(){ 
                    $('#schedules > tbody:last-child').append('<tr id="newrow"><td id="time_from"><input id="time_from"/></td><td id="time_to"><input id="time_to"/></td><td id="enabled"><input id="enabled"/></td><td id="saveicon"><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw" id="saveicon"></i></td></tr>');

                    //function for when the save new row icon is pressed
                    $('#saveicon').on('click',function(){ 
                        //Send data to script to store as now row in db
                        $.get( "/settings/insertSchedule/" + $('#newrow input#time_from').val() + "/" + $('#newrow input#time_to').val() + "/" +   $('#newrow input#enabled').val()  , function( data ) {

                            //Change input fields to text fields
                            $('#newrow td#time_from').text($('#newrow input#time_from').val());
                            $('#newrow td#time_to').text($('#newrow input#time_to').val());
                            $('#newrow td#enabled').text($('#newrow input#enabled').val());

                            //change checkmark icon into edit icon
                            $('#newrow i#saveicon').attr('class', 'fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-fw');
                            $('#newrow i#saveicon').attr('id', 'editicon');                
                            $('#newrow td#saveicon').attr('id', 'edit');                

                            $('#newrow').attr('id',data);                
                            console.log(data);
                        });
                    });
                });


                //function for when the edit row icon is clicked
                var arr = {};
                $('#schedules').on('click','#edit',function() {
                    var rowid = ($(this).parent().attr('id'));
                    $(this).siblings().each(
                        function(){
                                //end of editing, change the icon back to a pencil and change the fiels back to text
                                if ($(this).find('input').length){
                                $(this).text($(this).find('input').val());
                                $('#editicon').attr('class', 'fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-fw');
                                arr[this.id] = $(this).html()
                            }
                            else {
                                //start of editing, change fields to input fields and icon to checkmark
                                var t = $(this).text();
                                $(this).html($('<input />',{'value' : t}).val(t));
                                $('#editicon').attr('class', 'fa fa-check fa-fw');
                            }
                    });

                    //Send updated data to script to store in DB.
                    if (Object.keys(arr).length > 0){
                        $.get( "/settings/updateSchedule/" + rowid + "/" + arr.time_from + "/" + arr.time_to    , function( data ) {});

                    }
                }); 



                </script>
```

Edit: I've simulated the problem in a slightly modified form in jsfiddle:  jsfiddle.net/15dd3j3v

Comment: Can you please reproduce the problem using https://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Great Idea, I've created a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/15dd3j3v/ Only problem is that I'm unable to really reproduce the issue, since the get command that normaly saves the new row in the db and returns the id is not not functioning.

Comment: You can skip API call, use a fake ID

Comment: I've now solved it bu assigning a random number. As you can see, editing and adding brings me to the right place in the code (see console), but when a new row is saved, and you click the edit button to edit that new row, it's again getting to the code for saving a new row.

Comment: I've seen that you have some troubles... I'm working to fix that... Let you know soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/15dd3j3v/5/

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="schedules" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Time from</th>
      <th>Time to</th>
      <th>Enabled</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr id="1">
      <td class="td_time_from">16:01</td>
      <td class="td_time_to">23:01</td>
      <td class="td_enabled">true</td>
      <td class="button"><button class="editBtn"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-fw" ></i> edit</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
      <td class="td_time_from">10:00</td>
      <td class="td_time_to">11:00</td>
      <td class="td_enabled">false</td>
      <td class="button"><button class="editBtn"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-fw"></i> edit</button></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="addRow"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> add row</button>
```

JS:

```
var fakeId = 3;

function getRowForSaving(){
    return '<tr id="newrow"><td class="td_time_from"><input class="input_time_from"/></td><td class="td_time_to"><input class="input_time_to" /></td><td class="td_enabled"><input class="input_enabled" /></td><td><button class="saveBtn"><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i>save</button><button class="cancelBtn">&times;</button></td></tr>';
}

function getRowWithData(id, time_from, time_to, enabled){
    return '<tr id="'+id+'"><td class="td_time_from">'+time_from+'</td><td class="td_time_to">'+time_to+'</td><td class="td_enabled">'+enabled+'</td><td><button class="editBtn"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-fw" ></i> edit</button></td></tr>';
}
function getRowForEdit(id, time_from, time_to, enabled){
    return '<tr id="'+id+'"><td class="td_time_from"><input class="input_time_from" value="'+time_from+'" /></td><td class="td_time_to"><input class="input_time_to" value="'+time_to+'" /></td><td class="td_enabled"><input class="input_enabled" value="'+enabled+'" /></td><td><button class="saveEditBtn"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-fw" ></i> Save edit</button></td></tr>';
}

//function for when the addrow action is used
$('#addRow').on('click', function() {
  $('#schedules > tbody:last-child').append(getRowForSaving());
});

$('#schedules').on('click', '.cancelBtn', function(){
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});

$('#schedules').on('click', '.saveBtn', function(){
    var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
  var time_from = $row.find('.input_time_from').val();
  var time_to = $row.find('.input_time_to').val();
  var enabled = $row.find('.input_enabled').val();
  console.log("Save this datas \ntime_from: " + time_from + "\ntime_to: " + time_to + "\nenabled:"+enabled);

  // SAVING FUNCTION

  $row.replaceWith(getRowWithData(fakeId,time_from, time_to, enabled));
  fakeId++;
});

$('#schedules').on('click', '.editBtn', function(){
    var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
  var id = $row.attr('id');
  var time_from = $row.find('.td_time_from').text();
  var time_to = $row.find('.td_time_to').text();
  var enabled = $row.find('.td_enabled').text();

  console.log("EDIT MODE for row: " + id );

  $row.replaceWith(getRowForEdit(id, time_from, time_to, enabled));
});

$('#schedules').on('click', '.saveEditBtn', function(){
    var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
  var id = $row.attr('id');
  var time_from = $row.find('.input_time_from').val();
  var time_to = $row.find('.input_time_to').val();
  var enabled = $row.find('.input_enabled').val();
  console.log("Save the edit this datas \nid: "+id+"\ntime_from: " + time_from + "\ntime_to: " + time_to + "\nenabled:"+enabled);

  // SAVE EDIT FUNCTION

  $row.replaceWith(getRowWithData(id, time_from, time_to, enabled));
});
```

I've re-written some part of your code to make what you require. I've tried to use your style of coding to much as possible. Some parts are written long-winded to aid comprehension.

However I suggest you use a pre written library like JQuery Grid http://www.trirand.com/blog/ that is the best solution because you must work hard to get a good grid with deep functionality like JQgrid

Write a comment if you need help, remember to vote up and check the answer if its help byeee

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, your sample can make me better understand how to do this. I do know there are a lot of datagrids you can use "out of the box", but I like to create my own to better understand javascrip/jquery

Comment: I agree with you, The own code writing is more satisfactory

Answer (score 0):

I would go with jquery datatables, https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

u can add, edit, delete rows, and perform what ever, like call php to update database after doing so